# Firebase Image Load with Glide not working with Android SDK 28 (Pie)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-glide

I am using Glide to show image using the url fetched by the firebase storage. This works perfectly fine previously but it now occurring problem and there is no error in the logcat, so I am unable to rectify the bug. Here is my code for the image loading.

```
public void showImage(){
    mStorageRef.child("TimeTable").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(this,new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

            url = uri.toString();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(TimeTable.this, "Loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            GlideApp.with(TimeTable.this)
                    .load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    .into(image);

        }
    });
}
```

and Here is the AppGlideModule Class as per Doc:

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

@Override
public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {

    registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
            new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
 }}
```

It is showing a blank screen no error not anything. I checked the url of the image the url is correct and it loads image when open in browser but It does not working with Glide.

I later found out that it is working with devices running lower than SDK27 (Android 8) and found that there is an issue with Glide After SDK27, but there is no solution anywhere. I already tried the method of putting `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in Manifest, but it didn't make much of a difference.